# SPF record descriptive text broken into two separate quoted strings

Tags: dns, spf

I would like to know if anyone else has ever had this happen. I have a domain whose DNS is hosted with rackspace. When I configured the TXT (SPF) record, I never include quotes for the descriptive text -- most hosts don't allow you to enter them anyway. Here's an example of a string that I entered when configuring an SPF record on rackspace:

```
v=spf1 mx a include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

But when I query rackspace's DNS servers directly, I get the following result:

```
host -t txt example.tld
example.tld descriptive text "v=spf1 mx a include:_spf.google.com " "~all"
```

If I query the TXT record of another domain, whose DNS is hosted by Network Solutions, and whose SPF info was entered in the exact same way, I get the following result:

```
host -t txt example.tld
example.tld descriptive text "v=spf1 mx a include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Notice, the descriptive text is one continuous string, not two as in the result before it.

I get the same results with dig. I haven't yet been able to confirm whether this is causing any problems (yet), but it is the first time I've seen the descriptive text broken into two separate double-quoted strings. I've asked rackspace tech support about it and they have confirmed that they're seeing the same thing, but they couldn't explain why. Furthermore, this *wasn't* happening just a few days ago -- I know because I had to paste some TXT query results from one of the rackspace hosted domains into an e-mail. I pasted them verbatim. Before posting this, I checked the message in my sent mail to confirm whether it wasn't happening then, or it was but I simply didn't notice -- it wasn't.

Has anyone else ever seen this? Does it even matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there is at least one way that could reasonably happen. If that is what's happening, it's not a problem. But since you're hiding the domain, I can't check if that's it or not.

Comment: There are some SPF implementations that does not handle the split up records as they should. These implementations only uses the first string, which can result in PERMERROR if the string is split in the middle of a mechanism. In your case these implementations would just ignore the "~all", and then most likely return NEUTRAL if none of the other mechanisms match.

Comment: It's just really odd; when I input the text into Rackspace's DNS manager, it isn't split, quoted, etc. It seems like there's something up with the form or the script that processes the form data. It doesn't appear to be causing any problems though, but I would like to eventually find out what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spf record is greater than 255 characters, it shows as two strings.

These strings get concatenated at the spf verifier to form the single spf record.

The limit of 255 characters is a part of the standard for spf records.

Ref:
https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00356/0/Can-I-have-a-TXT-or-SPF-record-longer-than-255-characters.html

Comment: It's nice to finally have an answer on this. Not that it ever caused any trouble or anything. Thanks!

Comment: Also -- The original string wasn't 255 characters but that doesn't mean rackspace wasn't breaking up certain parts of the string for whatever reason. I have another domain on rackspace whose SPF looks like this:  `example.tld descriptive text "v=spf1 mx a ip4:50.57.219.119/32 ip4:50.57.219.120/30 ip4:50.57.219.124/32 ip4:67.192.46.10/32 ip4:72.3.165.4/31 ip4:72.3.165.6/32 ip4:72.3.204.183/32 ip4:72.32.1.164/30 ip4:72.32.1.168/32 ip4:174.143.28.59/32 ip4:174.143.28.60/30 include:_spf.google.com " "~all"`  **that** one breaks right at the 255 character limit.